# RGBA and RGB to Hex

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a method which can convert RGB or RGBA string to hex format. i found solution but not in one method like method 1 => rgbToHex and for RGBA rgbaToHex i want to combine them so it can return  hex value of both RGB and RGBA

RGB method:

```
    // convert RGB color data to hex
function rgb2hex(r, g, b) {
    if (r > 255 || g > 255 || b > 255)
        throw "Invalid color component";
    return ((r << 16) | (g << 8) | b).toString(16);
}
```

RGBA method:

```
function rgba2hex(r, g, b, a) {
    if (r > 255 || g > 255 || b > 255 || a > 255)
        throw "Invalid color component";
    return (256 + r).toString(16).substr(1) +((1 << 24) + (g << 16) | (b << 8) | a).toString(16).substr(1);
}
```

What i want:

```
 //takes both RGB and RGBA and convert to HEX like  #000000
   // input will be string like this => rgb(0,0,0) or rgba(255,255,255, 0.5)
    function anyToHex() {
     return; // hex value
    }
```

i created my solution which can take take any string rgb or rgba and then return a HEX value
Here is my soution:

```
function componentToHex(c) {
    var hex = c.toString(16);
    return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}
function anytoHEX(string) {

    rgb = string.substring(4, string.length-1).replace(/ /g, '').split(',');
    R = rgb[0].replace("(", "");
    G = rgb[1];
    B = rgb[2];

    return "#" + componentToHex(R) + componentToHex(G) + componentToHex(B);

}

console.log(anytoHEX('rgba(0,0,0,0)'));
```

Comment: Aloha! It's a bit tough to see what the actual problem is. Have you tried combining those methods into one yet? Could you tell us where you got with the `anyToHex` function so we can give specific help?

Comment: Do you understand how each of these functions work? You should spend some time to do that, then it should be easy for you to combine both.

Comment: @FelixKling, You're right. Btw, @Sunilmeena want it like `#000000`, therefore **a** doesn't matters!

Comment: You may also want to consider checking if each input is greater than 0, since negative values would also be invalid.

Comment: @Rahul: I think it's just an incomplete example. Because `255` certainly doesn't map to `00` ;)

Comment: @FelixKling I think she was just giving an example of the # format that she wants, wouldn't make sense to have these two separate functions if all she wanted was rgb in the answer, why bother including a?

Comment: stupid question: the hex-value `0xC0FFEE`, is that `rgb(192, 255, 238)` or `rgba(0, 192, 255, 0.9333);`?

Comment: @Thomas, The first one, the 0x just defines it as being a hex value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make it a wrapper,and call the function based on the arguments passed

```
 //takes both RGB and RGBA and convert to HEX like  #000000
   // input will be string like this => rgb(0,0,0) or rgba(255,255,255, 0.5)
    function anyToHex(r, g, b, a) {
      if(a === undefined){
         return rgb2hex(r, g, b);
      }
     return rgba2hex(r, g, b, a);
    }
```

Comment: That's not quite right. That means if `a` is `0`, it won't be considered.

Comment: but i have string values not in array

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to give him an idea of creating a wrapper

Comment: @Sunilmeena: *"but i have string values not in array"* What does that mean?

Comment: I mean how will i extract R, G,B and Aplha from string

Comment: @Sunilmeena: Have you looked at [RGB to Hex and Hex to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5623838/218196) ?

Comment: Yes but there is  no solution which i want

Answer (score 2):

In javascript, all function parameters are optional, so if one is omitted it will be `undefined`. So, you can check with something like

```
if (a === undefined) {
  // return rgb2hex
else {
  // return rgba2hex
}
```

Note, you don't want to do `if (a)` here since 0 is a valid value for a, but will result in false and just returning rgb.